# GNU Screen window rename nuisance

Tags: gnu-screen

I like to pop up a screen session with pre-opened SSH connections to the primary servers that I administrate at the office. I give these windows each a very brief name, typically 2-4 characters, so they appear in my screen status bar with those names. So I'll have a screen entry that looks like

```
0$ jen1 ...
```

Now, when I need to switch to that server and do anything even as simple as fetch a directory listing, that name suddenly expands and becomes

```
0$ ghellings@devjenkins01
```

The same happens for each and every window as I access it, making my status bar quickly overflow the horizontal width of my screen. I would like to lock the name in place at window creation time and prevent client applications from changing it. I don't want any applications to be able to change the screen window title (quite the opposite of what lots of people seem to be asking). This becomes especially cumbersome once I change to that screen and open a directory somewhere. Then the screen title becomes

```
 (0*$ ghellings@devjenkins01:/opt/somepackage/software/subdirectory)
```

I want it to only change the active status so it will always read either

```
`0$ jen1` or `(0*$ jen1)`
```

Is there a way for me to lock the window name in and prevent changing it?

Answer (score 10):

I found this early on in RHEL 7 testing and it would drive me nuts. What I discovered is that there was a change to `/etc/bashrc` in RHEL 7 that causes the naming of windows in `screen` and `tmux` to change whenever a command like `cd` or `ls` is run. In section screen*)

```
if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
    PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
else
## RHEL 7
    PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'

## RHEL 6
    PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
fi
```

So in RHEL 7 the change was from **]0;** to **k** in the PROMPT_COMMAND section.

I had considered opening a bug, but just never got around to it. I usually just change it manually on a fresh install.

- Changes made to update formatting

Answer (score 8):

Most probably, you have the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable set to something like

```
printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
```

I have exactly this on a CentOS 7 system. This sets the xterm window title after each command, which `screen` uses as window title.

Just unset `PROMPT_COMMAND` in your `.bashrc` or edit `/etc/bashrc` to not set it.

Comment: See below to make this more permanent.

Answer (score 2):

If you check `.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc`, you may see `if` or `case` which is related to `screen`.

In my case, it was something like:

```
if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
    PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
else
    PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
fi
```

under `case $TERM in` in `/etc/bashrc` file.

The problem was that I did not have the file `/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen` so `PROMPT_COMMAND` under `else` is used.

I just made an empty `/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen` file then titles of screen windows are not dynamically changed anymore!

Comment: Have to make the empty file executable or you'll get a warning every time bash is launched (eg at login for everyone).